# Using CSS, how do you create larger elements when the mouse is over them?

Tags: html, css, dropshadow

The effect seen is that the boxes increase in size when the mouse is over them, and there is a drop shadow too.

When the mouse is not over the boxes, they go back to the same size with no drop shadow.

**Normal:**

[image]

**Mouse over:**

[image]

Scroll over the boxes to see the effect [**here**](http://bestlinkbuildingservice.net/buy-facebook-likes.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hz97u/)

Hovering over elements and making them larger can be done in many ways, and it depends on your layout requirements and the framework your using.

Since those boxes appear to be div's with CSS3 box shadow property, you can do something like that in pure CSS using :hover

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.box {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  border: 6px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box:hover{
  width: 250px;
  /* This is 52px total. 1/2 of that is for top and the other half is for bottom. */
  height: 452px;
  /* Below we are not using -26px for margin-top because .box has 6px border and 10px margin. */
  /* That 16px is then divide by 2 since it's for both top and bottom, or 8px per side. */
  /* Having said that, 26px - 8px is 18px. We need negative value to position it correctly. */
  margin-top: -18px;
 -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 50px red;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px red;
 box-shadow:         0 0 50px red;    
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

[**Revised jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wZD6c/)

[image]

Comment: How do you put a image with a link in one of those boxes?

Comment: That depends on your HTML and Layout requirements. [**Examples**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hz97u/8/).  Note classname `image` requires a framework, like `JavaScript` or `jQuery` so you can use that to construct a link to follow.

Comment: That is really great. Last question, how do you put a href in this line: <div class="box image">3</div> ?

Comment: About your last question: What is a href really?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I mean a HTML link to a specific page or a URL link

Comment: Same question, what is a HTML/URL link really made from?

Comment: Box 3 does not contain a link to, for example , www.website.com/index.HTML.

Comment: What are **links** apart of? Same question as the other two times. The answer is an `anchor`. Therefore, use: `<div class="box image"><a href="www.website.com/index.HTML">3</a></div>`

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this using "transform: scale(x,y)" to zoom your element.

E.g.

```
 div:hover{
 transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
-o-transform: scale(1.5, 1.25);
}
```

will zoom your div by 1.5 times on x-axis and keep 1.25 times on y-axis.

To add shadow -

```
div:hover{
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplished with some HTML and CSS.  They're commonly called "Dropdown" menus or "pop-out" menus and there are tons of tutorials on how to make them; here's one:

http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/tutorial/